# How to do OpenJPA enhancement with Ant + IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, ant, openjpa

This is driving me crazy and I'm shocked that [official documentation](http://openjpa.apache.org/enhancement-with-ant.html) is absolutely useles.

Here is what I have:

- IntelliJ IDEA 11
- OpenJPA 2.1.1

Since openjpa is added into list of used libraries I already had classpath to OpenJPA which looks like this

```
<path id="library.openjpa.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib/openjpa">
        <patternset refid="library.patterns"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

According to official documentation I added following target

```
<target name="enhance">
    <copy includeemptydirs="false" todir="${basedir}/lib/openjpa">
        <fileset dir="src" excludes="**/*.launch, **/*.java"/>
    </copy>

    <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask">
        <classpath refid="library.openjpa.classpath"/>
    </taskdef>

    <openjpac>
        <classpath refid="library.openjpa.classpath"/>
    </openjpac>
</target>
```

It gives me exception

> C:\work\prj\build.xml:283:  org.apache.openjpa.util.MetaDataException:
>   MetaDataFactory could not be configured
>   (conf.newMetaDataFactoryInstance() returned null). This might mean
>   that no configuration properties were found. Ensure that you have a
>   META-INF/persistence.xml file, that it is available in your classpath,
>   or that the properties file you are using for configuration is
>   available. If you are using Ant, please see the  or
>    attributes of the task's nested  element.
>   This can also occur if your OpenJPA distribution jars are corrupt, or
>   if your security policy is overly strict.

I tested with [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and can see that it **opens and reads** `persistence.xml`.

Some person [filed bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OPENJPA-2021) having problems I have and the answer he got was that finding `persistence.xml` is not a source of problem.

Questions are:

1. What can I do to make it work ?
2. Can I make it work by skipping need for `persistence.xml` and just specifying pattern for .class files I want to be enhanced ?
3. It's more Ant question. How can I make OpenJPA enhancer to look for `persistence.xml` in directory other than where `openjpa-2.1.1.jar` resides ?

Comment: Have you verified that the META-INF directory is on your classpath?

Comment: I don't know how to specify additional classpath directory in Ant script. But just to be sure I copied `persistence.xml` into directory where OpenJPA's jar sits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I couldn't make it work without undocumented `propertiesFile`. Here is version that works for me. Also specifying persistence-unit via `#` makes it fail with NullReferenceException.

```
<target name="enhance">
    <taskdef name="openjpac" classname="org.apache.openjpa.ant.PCEnhancerTask">
        <classpath refid="library.openjpa.classpath"/>
    </taskdef>

    <openjpac>
        <classpath refid="library.openjpa.classpath"/>
        <classpath location="${reporting.output.dir}"/>
        <config propertiesFile = "${basedir}/src/META-INF/persistence.xml"/>
    </openjpac>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you might have missed an important part from the documentation. Your `library.openjpa.classpath` is missing a reference to your Entities, and the location of the persistence.xml file. Try adding that and see how it goes.

```
<path id="jpa.enhancement.classpath">
  <pathelement location="bin"/> <!-- add something like this -->

  <!-- lib contains all of the jars that came with the OpenJPA binary download -->
  <fileset dir="lib">
    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
</path>
```

Comment: Nah, when it can't find my entities it gives ClassNotFound exception on them. I managed to make it work via command line and via Ant. Four hours of my life I'll never get back.

Comment: If you put you META-INF/persistence.xml into bin, it should have worked.

Comment: No luck :( Even though I see that `java.exe` process accesses `persistence.xml`. I managed to make it work like [this](http://pastebin.com/9bxWYQR3). But I'm unhappy that I specify absolute path to .xml in `propertiesFile` attribute. Could you tell me how I can make it work by specifying only name of the file and defining additional class path elsewhere ? I tried couple options but it didn't work :( Thanks!